# Navbar active state not correctly synchronized

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My menu doesn't work. For example when I click on the cart, the menu active is still the home. What seems to be the problem? Thanks!

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">company</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span>&nbsp;Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;Cart</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></i><span>&nbsp;Register</span></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>&nbsp;Login</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/47r5Q/.

Comment: You need to add/remove the `active` class as needed. Bootstrap won't do that for you. This can be done with server-side code, JS code, or just by editing the HTML -- depends entirely on what works best for you.

Comment: You don't need to copy paste bootstrap in like you did in the fiddle. You can just add it as an external resource. Making it much easier to read: http://jsfiddle.net/47r5Q/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this As @Blazemonger mentioned, you should implement your own logic. You could do this server side or client side. Because I don't know what you use on the server side, I will show how to easily solve it with jQuery.

Idea is to check the current url and if current url == navigation url, the add class active.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.navbar-nav > li > a').each(function(i, a)
    {
        var $a = $(a);
        var url = $a.attr('href');
        if(location.pathname.indexOf(url) == 1)
        {
            $a.parent().addClass('active');
        }
        else
        {
            $a.parent().removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

location.pathname returns /url-path, so in your example /login.php. To match is with login.php, you need to check if url starts at second character (skip /). If you update your url and prepend them with /, then you can change index from 1 to 0 to make it work. Hopefully it makes sense.

This is very simple code (of course, you can make it much better), but it's a simple example how to make it work.